# Why doesn't dup2 occur in sequential order?

Tags: c, process, sequence, dup2, dup

Here is a code snippet.

```
int saved_stdout = dup(1);
int fd = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0640);

close(1);
dup(fd);
close(fd);

printf("This text should go into the file\n");

//restore stdout
dup2(saved_stdout, 1);
printf("stdout restore");
```

I am trying to learn about dup and dup2. So I initially connected my file.txt to stdout. So whenever I use printf, I should be writing to file.txt instead of stdout. But I want to restore it back as well once I am done with this usage, so I use dup2 at the end as well.

The problem is that the text "This text should go into the file\n" never actually goes into the file, but gets printed on stdout. Why so? I straced for it, only to find that dup2 call occurs before that printf("This text..."); statement, why so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem may be due to output buffering. `stdout` is fully buffered if it's not writing to a terminal, so when you redirect it to the file with `dup()` it will be buffered. Try flushing the output after the `printf()`.

```
printf("This text should go into the file\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: While `fflush()` "works", I suspect it's for the wrong reason. There's something more subtle going on here, as simply putting any `printf()` immediately after the `open()` also works. The problem is the mixing of file descriptors and FILE structures, which is perhaps undefined territory, meaning you might get different results on different systems. The correct way to do what you want is to `freopen("file.txt", "w", stdout)`. That operation is clearly defined.

Comment: @gilez I think as long as you flush between writing something and changing the file descriptor, you should be safe. Although I admit I'm a little hesitant with this answer, because I suspect that the buffering is initialized when `stdin` is opened, not when `printf()` occurs. But it could be lazy and do it at the first write.

Comment: @Barmar, I suspect the stdout `FILE *` is somehow not initialized completely until used, so the order of operations matters too, and my `printf()` option thus makes it "work". You could be correct about the buffering too. It's all a bit dodgy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I removed my prior answer as it's wrong.... But when you use `printf()` you're using the `FILE *` for `stdout`, inside of which there's a descriptor or something pointing to the terminal. Changing fd 1 is apparently not changing that.

I'm getting inconsistent results with testing, so giving up here. I just want to add that putting this line just after the `open()` makes it work for me, which highlights the obscure behaviour:

```
printf("fileno is %i\n", fileno(stdout));
```

Don't mix `FILE *` operations such as `printf()` with file descriptor manipulation. You should use `write()` with the descriptor.

Comment: `dup()` does use the first available descriptor. His code is how things were done before `dup2()` was added.

Comment: @Barmar, I think the confusion is over what "first available" means. Is it 1 because that's closed, or 4 because that's never been used?

Comment: @posixKing, turns out it's using 4 on my system, and perhaps OP's. Why "should"?  On linux the description in the man page is not precise.

Comment: On my system (OS X) the man page says "the lowest numbered descriptor currently
     not in use by the process."

Comment: @Barmar, that is similar to my Linux system. But it's not doing what we seem to expect. Does it open 1 or 4 on your system? See http://pastebin.com/tQbGrMLe for a compilable copy.

Comment: Your program prints `fd`, not what `dup()` returns.

Comment: However, you're right that `dup2()` is preferred. Otherwise, you have to depend on knowing that `stdin` hasn't been closed.